# Recursive method why does it stop?

Tags: java, recursion

i am trying to learn abit about recursive methods and is writing a method for my binary tree that counts the sum of all the integers in the tree my code works fine and all but i am still abit confused about how the application knows when to stop. my code looks like the this:

```
    public int sum(){

    return sum(overallRoot);
}

private int sum(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        return root.data + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
    }

}
```

(the above code is from my nodeTree class)

The next code is from my main class:

```
public class TreeClient {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntTree tree = new IntTree(12);
    System.out.println(tree.sum());
}
```

}

So the question is (maybe for many quite simple) but how does my application know when to stop? ive tried with simple system out prints to figur out but as far as my understanding is right now the method would call it self in an endless loop?

hope someone has time to respond!

Comment: Hint: In what case does your `sum()` function *not* call itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any recursive program, your iteration stops when a **`base condition`** is reached.. Here your base condition is : -

```
if (root == null) {
    return 0;
}
```

So, when your `root.left` and `root.right`, in the following `return` statement in else block both becomes null, you have reached your `base condition`, and hence your loop stops..

```
return root.data + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple really

Take the line from the *sum* function:

```
return root.data + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
```

When you get to the bottom of the tree, *root.left* will be null, and so will *root.right*.  Thus, when the above line calls *sum(root.left)* the *sum* function drops into the other half of the *if* statement:

```
return 0;
```

Thus, the *sum* function no longer calls itself, and so stops recursing

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it does not go into an endless loop because there is a condition when it does not call itself recursively anymore.

The condition is

```
if (root == null)
```

when it does

```
return 0;
```

rather than calling itself again

```
return root.data + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
```